# need to get a class after switch case in swift?

Tags: swift, class, switch-statement, return, any

I need to get the class as response after the switch case in swift, I get compilation problems with this function.

```
func getOptClass(signal : String) -> AnyClass{

var result = AnyClass

switch(signal){
    case "IntRR":
        result = BPMClass.self
        break

    case "BPM":
        result = BPMClass.self
        break

    case "ECG":
        result = ECGClass.self
        break

    default:
        result = nil
        break
}
return result
}
```

Here is the error:

```
    Swift Compiler Error Group
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:68:18: Expected member name or constructor call after type name
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:68:18: Use '.self' to reference the type object
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:72:22: Cannot assign value of type 'BPMClass.Type' to type 'AnyClass.Protocol' (aka 'AnyObject.Type.Protocol')
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:76:22: Cannot assign value of type 'BPMClass.Type' to type 'AnyClass.Protocol' (aka 'AnyObject.Type.Protocol')
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:80:22: Cannot assign value of type 'ECGClass.Type' to type 'AnyClass.Protocol' (aka 'AnyObject.Type.Protocol')
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:84:22: Nil cannot be assigned to type 'AnyClass.Protocol' (aka 'AnyObject.Type.Protocol')
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:87:12: Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyClass.Protocol' (aka 'AnyObject.Type.Protocol') to return type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')
```

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting?  People will be able to help a lot more if you have that information.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I probably a function returning a generic type representing your class. You could try something like this :

```
func getOptClass<T>(signal : String) -> T {
switch(signal) {
    case "IntRR", "BPM":
      return T as! BPMClass
    case "ECG":
      return T as! ECGClass
    default:
      return nil
   }
}
```

Here the `T` represents any type so any class that you create. In each switch case I cast this type by your corresponding class. You don't need to put break statements like in JAVA only if you want to handle particular cases. I also simplify your switch and I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have this errors, when compile :    `/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:70:20: Cannot convert return expression of type 'BPMClass.Type' to return type 'T'
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:73:20: Cannot convert return expression of type 'ECGClass.Type' to return type 'T'
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:76:20: Nil is incompatible with return type 'T'`

Comment: Can you post the code of your BPMClass and others class ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare result as an AnyClass, not set its value to that:

```
var result: AnyClass!
```

then add your switch statement. You don't need the breaks; they're not needed in swift; starting a new case statement will break the previous, unless you add fall through.

Also, you should return AnyClass?, since you have a nil option.

Comment: I already tried that, I get an error :
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:82:18: Expected member name or constructor call after type name
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:82:26: Add arguments after the type to construct a value of the type
/Users/gab/Desktop/desktopAppli/mobileApp/mobileApp/GlobalCstes.swift:82:26: Use '.self' to reference the type object

Answer (score 0):

```
func getOptClass(signal : String) -> AnyClass? {
    var result: AnyClass?

    switch(signal) {
    case "IntRR", "BPM":
        result = BPMClass.self
    case "ECG":
        result = ECGClass.self
    default:
        result = nil
    }

    return result
}
```

Notice the return type is now optional. It's the only way you'll be allowed to return nil.